# Display JSON property

Tags: javascript

So I have a dropdown component created in Vue.js that enables the user to drag and drop a file, after he has dropped the file he is redirected to another page where that file is displayed as JSON. Currently my JSON looks like that:

```
{"upload":{"uuid":"fa90093a-534e-40fb-ab53-20edd78fad08","progress":0,"total":5197,"bytesSent":0,"filename":"svg-test.svg","chunked":false,"totalChunkCount":1},"status":"added","previewElement":{},"previewTemplate":{}}
```

I want to display only the filename":"svg-test.svg property, how can I achieve that? Here are my components:

```
 mounted() {
   var dropzoneComponent = new Dropzone (
     '#dropzone',
     {
       url: 'file/upload',
       createImageThumbnails: false,
       previewsContainer: '#template-preview',
       acceptedFiles: '.svg',
       init: function() {
       this.on ('complete', function() {
          window.location.href='http://localhost:8080/edit-draft'
          })
      this.on('addedfile', function(file) {
            localStorage.setItem('file', JSON.stringify(file))
          })
       },
     }
   )
  },




Here it gets called from the LocalStorage
    data: () => ({
        mode: "edit",
        svgFile: localStorage.getItem('file'),
        floorStore: store.floor
      }),
```

Comment: Can you please check my answer? If you have any questions - feel free to ask.

Comment: Cool! Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could access it as follows:

`JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('file')).upload.filename`

The key point here is that you first need to parse it, because when you save it to localStorage you stringified it.